# Adding an single entity multiple relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity and I'm trying to add it to a collection in two different entities.

What I want to achieve is something like

```
[1] => DomainUser { name = "bob" }
DomainGroup.Users = [ 1 ]
LocalGroup.Users = [ 1 ]
```

When I try to save changes, however, I get `Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'DomainGroup_Users_Source' of the relationship 'Server.DomainTools.Models.DomainGroup_Users' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.`

Here's my entities:

This is where I feel my issues lies: DomainUser

```
public class DomainUser 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string DistinguishedName { get; set; }
    public int AdminCount { get; set; }
    public int PwdLastSet { get; set; }
    public string AdsPath { get; set; }
    public int LastLogon { get; set; }
    public int LastLogoff { get; set; }
    public int LockoutTime { get; set; }
    public int AccountExpires { get; set; }
    public int BadPwdCount { get; set; }
    public int LogonCount { get; set; }
}
```

And here are the two entities that I'm trying to add DomainUser to: DomainGroup and LocalGroup

```
public class DomainGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<DomainUser> Users { get; set; }
    public List<DomainGroup> Groups { get; set; }
    public string DistinguishedName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DomainGroup()
    {
        Users = new List<DomainUser>();
        Groups = new List<DomainGroup>();
    }
}

public class LocalGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public List<LocalUser> LocalUsers { get; set; }
    public List<DomainUser> DomainUsers { get; set; }
    public List<DomainGroup> DomainGroups { get; set; }
    public List<LocalGroup> LocalGroups { get; set; }

    public LocalGroup()
    {
        LocalUsers = new List<LocalUser>();
        LocalGroups = new List<LocalGroup>();
        DomainUsers = new List<DomainUser>();
        DomainGroups = new List<DomainGroup>();
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you map them? I don't really see a clear foreign key

Comment: Domain => [DomainGroup] and Domain => [Computer => [LocalGroup]]

Comment: But what is the foreign key? Did you do it through fluent mapping?

Comment: No.  I just did it through List<type> relationships.

Comment: Then it can't work. You need a foreign key from `DomainUser` to `DomainGroup` and `LocalGroup` for a one-to-many

Comment: When my model gets created in the database, I get DomainUser => {DomainGroup_Id, LocalGroup_Id}.  Now I'm realizing that won't work either.  I need a join table because DomainUser can be related to many LocalGroups ... and DomainGroups.